# BASIC Javascript slider/rollovers NO JQUERY

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn `JavaScript`.

So I can build my own sliders, rollovers, really awesome `JavaScript` web stuff :) - without the use of plugins and such.

I was hoping someone could head me in the directions of building these on my own - tutorials `Jsfiddle`, etc. any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried?  What specifically is your question?  If you don't know where to start, I suggest reading the source code of one of the plugins you already like to use.  If you could give an example of a specific plugin, and ask a specific question on how it is built, we could better describe how it works and point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

http://symmetrycode.com/super-easy-javascript-slider-tutorial/

This was one of the first finds in a google search for "javascript slider tutorial".  I would suggest using Google for everything else you're after.

Answer (score 0):

this one looks to be written in css and html5 using the type tag

```
type="range"
```

http://developerdrive.com/demo/slider_control/demo.html